# What would cause newly checked out git files to show edits (not line endings, actual edits)?

Tags: git

I have a bunch of files showing "changes to be committed" right after a fresh clone. Naturally my first step was to check the changes assuming it to be line endings or file mode changes, and it turns out to be actual lines of code changed, for example:

```
$git status

[snip]
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    [snip]
    modified:   custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/en_us.CSTM.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git diff custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/en_us.CSTM.php

diff --git a/custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/en_us.CSTM.php     b/custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/en_us.CSTM.php
index 47b9668e27..85bb53235b 100755
--- a/custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/en_us.CSTM.php
+++ b/custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/en_us.CSTM.php
@@ -1,316 +1,7 @@
 <?php 
-$app_list_strings['repeat_type_dom'] = array (
-  '' => 'None',
-  'Daily' => 'Daily',
-  'Weekly' => 'Weekly',
-  'Monthly' => 'Monthly',
[snip]
```

Those lines are actually removed in the file which I can see when I verify the file itself. I didn't do as this is a fresh clone. I also verified the master branch on GitHub which version of the file is latest and it's the version with the lines removed. How is this possible?

To add some additional context:

Some months ago on a fresh checkout of this repo I got this error:

```
warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:

  'custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/en_us.CSTM.php'
  'custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/en_us.cstm.php'
```

...and then the list of changes mentioned above. Someone has evidently fixed the duplicate files as they no longer exist in the repo, but the file changes still appear when the repo is freshly cloned.

EDIT:

For the sake of argument:

```
$ git ls-files '*.php'
[snip]
en_us.CA_ASSEMENTS.php
en_us.CSTM.php
en_us.CallType.php
[snip]
```

Comment: Try `git ls-files '*.php'` to find out if the case-sensitive duplicates are still there.

Comment: They are not still there as noted above

Comment: Is the repository public? If so, others could verify your claim that the problem is fixed for particular commit hash IDs. Note that *no* **existing** commit can ever be changed, so the problem likely persists in older commits—it would be gone only if those commits themselves are also entirely gone (which necessitates removal of all subsequent commits, which is why this is unlikely: one has to do a full history rewrite).

Comment: I’m aware commits can’t be changed, as I’ve been using git for over a decade. I’ve simply never encountered an issue like this, and no I’m afraid the repo is private. I’m happy to provide the output of commands you’d like me to run to verify.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be related to the fact the some systems are case sensitive with respect to filenames, while others are not. If your system  does not respect case, then perhaps .CSTM gets checked out, and the .cstm gets checked out and overwrites .CSTM, which make it look like there are changes to .CSTM
(or visa-versa)

In that case it would not look to you like there are two, because you would only see one.
I think the suggestion above using git ls-files '*.php' might be useful to answer this.

My main point is that it might not look to you like they are both there even if they are both there.

Comment: I just set up a test repo in GitHub with two files, a.txt and A.txt with different content. When I list the repo in the GitHub console I see both files. When I check it out locally I get the same error I saw and quoted above: "warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:" and only one of them actually survives in my OS (Mac). The problem is in the private repo this question refers to, the duplicates have been removed already (so there is no error on checkout).

Comment: and when I list the private repo in the GitHub I can confirm the duplicates are not there, so the problem is not as simple as your answer suggests. I have added an edit to the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973157/deleting-ghost-files-that-dont-exist-in-the-file-system-but-are-left-in-git-aft  I believe this question may have some relevant clues about your issue.

Comment: Hmm, yes, interesting! I’ll follow this rabbit hole and post back. Thanks @RandyLeberknight